# Can I ask here a question about MS office?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

Can I ask here a question about MS Office Word? (specifically about Multilevel list)

Comment: Well not here exactly (on meta) but on the main site [su] yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can ask about using MS Office Word.

To help get answers remember to provide info such as your version, maybe what OS you're using, and what you've attempted so far to help narrow down the focus and relevancy of answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !